# Solving the travelling salesman problem using a genetic algorithm

Tags: performance, go, traveling-salesman

I've got a simple program written in Golang that takes a map as input and tries to solve the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) by using a genetic algorithm. My Crossover method is a real performance killer due to intense use of `make()` (allocate memory / will provoke the GC).

What I'd like to do - and yet failed to do is outsource the creation of `newGenes`. `pCrossover` and therefore the size of `newGenes` will be the same over all calls of the function, so I'd like to avoid creating that slice again and again.

I am also interested in any suggestions for improvements of my coding style in Golang and other performance improvements I can take a look at.

[My source is at Github](https://github.com/halfdan/TravellingSalesman/blob/master/ga/travelling_salesman.go#L104).

Here is an excerpt of the function I am trying to improve:

```
func (ts *TravellingSalesman) Crossover() {
    // Crossover        
    var nCrossover = int(ts.pCrossover * float64(ts.nGenes))
    var newGenes = make([]ga.Gene, nCrossover)
    for i:=0; i < nCrossover; i++ {
        newGenes[i].Data = make([]int, ts.geneLength)
        n := rand.Intn(ts.nGenes)
        m := rand.Intn(ts.nGenes)

        currentCity := ts.genes[n].Data[0];
        newGenes[i].Data[0] = currentCity
        for k:=1; k < ts.geneLength; k++ {
            nextN := findNextCity(&(ts.genes[n].Data), currentCity)
            nextM := findNextCity(&(ts.genes[m].Data), currentCity)

            existN := isInArray(&(newGenes[i].Data), nextN)
            existM := isInArray(&(newGenes[i].Data), nextM)

            // n exists, m doesnt -> take m
            if existN && !existM {
                newGenes[i].Data[k] = nextM
                currentCity = nextM
            } else if !existN && existM {
                newGenes[i].Data[k] = nextN
                currentCity = nextN
            } else if existN && existM {
                nextRandom := findNextRandomCity(newGenes[i].Data[0:k], &(ts.genes[n].Data))
                newGenes[i].Data[k] = nextRandom
                currentCity = nextRandom
            } else {
                // If both didn't exist, take the shorter one               
                distN := ts.distMatrix.GetDistance(currentCity-1, nextN-1)
                distM := ts.distMatrix.GetDistance(currentCity-1, nextM-1)

                // Take the shorter route
                if distN < distM {
                    newGenes[i].Data[k] = nextN
                    currentCity = nextN
                } else {
                    newGenes[i].Data[k] = nextM
                    currentCity = nextM
                }
            }
        }
    }

    copy(ts.genes, newGenes)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a slice for `Gene.Data`?

You just allocate

```
var allData := make([]int, nCrossover * ts.geneLength)
```

before entering the for loop and assign

```
newGenes[i].Data = allData[i * ts.geneLength: (i + 1) * ts.geneLength]
```

You'd cut down on the amount of allocations (and system calls) without changing much else (except `findNextCity` and `isInArray` - but they should be written to accept slices instead of array pointers anyway).

And you'd follow the advice given by the languages creators in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices).